# Align the window to center screen after stackpanel is collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

In my application, on button click i am setting a Stackpanel visibility to Collapsed and another button click again setting back to Visible.
This is happening fine. But when i window is not positioned center when that stackpanel is visible.
How to adjust itself when the stackpanel visibility is changed..
I tried calling this function after i change the Visibility of StackPanel.

```
private void CenterWindowOnScreen()
{
    double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
    double windowWidth = this.Width;
    double windowHeight = this.Height;
    this.Left = (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
    this.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);
}
```

But it is not aligning properly.   How to achieve this??

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you want to position a window to the center of the screen, you may use WindowStartupLocation: WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"

Comment: that is working fine during the form startup.. but after the form is shown i am hiding the stackpanel. that time the form width reduces. how to align it to center after hiding the stackpanel

Comment: Your reposition code works fine. It's when you call it may be an issue as `Window` my not be resized by then. Can users resize your `Window`? If not then try `SizeChanged` event of the `Window` and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046756/wpf-resize-complete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues to deal with here.

- `Resize` of the `Window` is not completed before the `CenterWindow()` is invoked(if invoked directly) thus calculations are incorrect.

**Solution:**
Do the `CenterWindow()` from a `SizeChanged` event handler and use a timer to not keep invoking `CenterWindow()` too often.

- Next we need to use `this.ActualWidth` and `this.ActualHeight` from the event handler for exact dimensions not `this.Width`...
- Your users might have multiple screen's(different resolutions among them as well). When you do a `CenterWindow(...)` for usability you would normally want to center to **current** screen than primary in most cases which your code wouldnt accomodate for.

**Solution:**
Need to use some WinForms helpers to get the actual screen and differentiate multiple screens.

- Finally WPF dimensions are DPI independent, while applying above steps would make it work fine at default 96dpi(win-8 think win-7 and vista too), you'd start seeing weird behavior when dpi is different on your user's machine.

**Solution:**
use dpi independent measures to sort that out.

Now putting this all together we get something like:

You'll need a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll`

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;

private readonly System.Timers.Timer _resizeTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);

public MainWindow() {
  InitializeComponent();

  ...

  SizeChanged += (sender, args) => {
    _resizeTimer.Stop();
    _resizeTimer.Start();
  };
  _resizeTimer.Elapsed +=
    (sender, args) =>
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(CenterWindowToCurrentScreen));
}

public static double GetDpiFactor(Visual window) {
  HwndSource windowHandleSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(window) as HwndSource;
  if (windowHandleSource != null && windowHandleSource.CompositionTarget != null) {
    Matrix screenmatrix = windowHandleSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
    return screenmatrix.M11;
  }
  return 1;
}

private void CenterWindowToCurrentScreen() {
  _resizeTimer.Stop();
  double dpiFactor = GetDpiFactor(this);
  var screen = Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
  double screenLeft = screen.Bounds.Left / dpiFactor;
  double screenTop = screen.Bounds.Top / dpiFactor;
  double screenWidth = screen.Bounds.Width / dpiFactor;
  double screenHeight = screen.Bounds.Height / dpiFactor;
  Left = ((screenWidth - ActualWidth) / 2) + screenLeft;
  Top = ((screenHeight - ActualHeight) / 2) + screenTop;
}
```

**Note:**

One thing the above code doesn't yet accommodate for is the actual task-bar dimensions. You can subtract them from the screen dimension as well to be even more precise if needed.